# Why doesnt IFTTT like my RSS feed?

Tags: rss, ifttt

I have followed the instructions on IFTTT and I have also checked the feed in a validator and it says that the feed is fine.

An example from the feed is here

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>CG Tipster - Tips of the day</title>
<link>http://www.facebook.com/CGTipster</link>
<description>A small selection of tips from CG Tipster</description>
<item>
<title>349465</title>
<link>http://www.cgtipster.com</link>
<description>
Kuwait SC vs Al-Jahra, Kuwait - Premier League - 16:15 - Home Win
</description>
<pubDate>Thu, 29 Dec 2016 12:03:25 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">tag:349465</guid>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

IFTTT say that only the GUID and Date for each entry which this has.

I have tried changing the titles, URLS, dates and guids, but it still wont trigger.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.